# Button doesn't work when i put it in try block

Tags: java, android

I was developing an app, and I got into this:

FirstActivity:

```java
EditText inputCorrect = findViewById(R.id.inputCorrect);
Button calcButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);

try {
    int correctAmount = Integer.parseInt(inputCorrect.getText().toString());
    Intent resultPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),resultActivity.class);
    resultPage.putExtra("c_a",correctAmount);
    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(resultPage);
        }
    });
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
}
```

SecondActivity:

```java
Bundle myIntent = getIntent().getExtras();
int value =myIntent.getInt("c_a");
```

I wanted to pass an int through these activities, but when I press the button it doesn't work.

If I put the button void out of `try{ }`,it doesn't detect `resultPage`.

Any ideas? thank you so much.

Comment: you could start with "not hiding exceptions".  define "doesn't work", the button doesn't show up? what kind of Button is it? Are you sure you shouldn't use an ActionListener

Comment: Have you debugged your code and checked if you enter the onClick event?

Comment: I guess you're right , I should use onClick instead of ActionListener.

Comment: Let me try to see if it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it works on my side.

```
public class TestButtonNotWork extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_button_not_work);

        EditText inputCorrect = findViewById(R.id.inputCorrect);
        Button calcButton = findViewById(R.id.calculateButton);
        Log.d("TestButtonNotWork", "TANCOLO===> init views ");

        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    int correctAmount = Integer.parseInt(inputCorrect.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("TestButtonNotWork", "TANCOLO===> init views, correctAmount = " + correctAmount);

                    Intent resultPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
                    resultPage.putExtra("c_a", correctAmount);

                    Log.d("TestButtonNotWork", "TANCOLO===> start ResultActivity");
                    startActivity(resultPage);

                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    Log.d("TestButtonNotWork", "TANCOLO===> exception = " + exception);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Note:** `Integer.parseInt()` must use `try .. catch`, otherwise, it will crash

Comment: Thank you so much.The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do your intent work inside your calcButton click listener:

```
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     int correctAmount =  Integer.parseInt(inputCorrect.getText().toString());
Intent resultPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),resultActivity.class);
resultPage.putExtra("c_a",correctAmount);
        startActivity(resultPage);
    }
});
```

In your second activity replace getInt() with getIntExtra():

```
       Bundle myIntent = getIntent().getExtras();
       int value =myIntent.getIntExtra("c_a");
```